# What does body represent inside curly brackets and body inside round brackets in map operator in Rxjs?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs

I have 2 API calls in the application. I have seen **body** inside curly brackets in the map operator in one call e.g **map(({ body }: any) => {this.assembleOrder(body.data)})** and **body** inside round brackets in the map operator in second call e.g **map((body: any) => this.assembleOrder(body.data))**. what is the difference between them?

Code:

```js
public getOrder$(orderID: string): Observable<OrderModel[]> {
return this.http
  .get(`${this.Url}?orderID=${orderID}`,
    { observe: 'response' }
  )
  .pipe(
    map(({ body }: any) => {this.assembleOrder(body.data)})
  );
  }  
 

public upgradeOrder$(Order: OrderModel): Observable<OrderModel> {
return this.http
    .post(`${this.Url}deals/copy/${Order.id}/upgrade`, null)
    .pipe(
        map((body: any) => this.assembleOrder(body.data))
    );      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are seeing is called [Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring). It is a shorthand syntax for assigning variables that come from properties of an object.

Here's an example where 3 const are being defined from a "user" object:

```
const id   = user.id;
const name = user.name;
const age  = user.age;
```

Using object destructuring, this can be achieved in a single line:

```
const { id, name, age } = user;
```

---

In your example without the braces:

```
map((body: any) => this.assembleOrder(body.data))
```

there is no destructuring, so the `body` param, just takes the response from your http call.

In the example with the braces:

```
map(({ body }: any) => {this.assembleOrder(body.data)})
```

destructuring is used, so `body` receives the value from the body property of the http response.

without destructuring, it would look like:

```
map((response: any) => {this.assembleOrder(response.body.data)})
```